# Service don't run like it should on real device

Tags: java, android, service, gps, alarmmanager

Problem is when I run service on emulator(android 4.0.3), then all is working(data is sent once per hour), but when i run it on my phone it's start sending data every minute. I can't figure out why, hope someone can help me with this.

The service is sending data to http://gprsbtn.herokuapp.com/coordinates where it's going to database.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aravov.gprsbtn"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.aravov.gprsbtn.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="MyService"></service>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.aravov.gprsbtn;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void btnClc(View v) {
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void btnClc2(View v) {
        stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }
}
```

GPSTracker.java

```
package com.aravov.gprsbtn;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

MyService.java

```
package com.aravov.gprsbtn;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
        someTask();
        sendNotif();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void sendNotif() {
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_stat_gprsbtn, "Text in status bar",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Notification's title", "Notification's text", pendingIntent);
        startForeground(1992, notification);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        stop();
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBind");
        return null;
    }

    void someTask() {
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                action();
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("gprs.post"));
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("gprs.post"),0 );
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));

        // timer here <<< 1000 * 60 = 1 minute
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, 1000 * 60 * 60 , pendingIntent); 
    }


    public void action() {
        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(MyService.this);

        //final double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        //final double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        final String lat = Double.toString(gps.latitude);
        final String lon = Double.toString(gps.longitude);

        // check if GPS enabled     
        if(gps.canGetLocation())
        {
            //posting
            Thread t = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    postData(lat, lon);
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }

        else
        {
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
    }

    public void postData(String latitude, String longitude) {
        try {
            HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(p);  
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://gprsbtn.herokuapp.com/coordinates"); 
            JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
            params.put("latitude",latitude);
            params.put("longitude",longitude);
            StringEntity ent = new StringEntity(params.toString());
            post.setEntity(ent);
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            client.execute(post); 

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDataSent");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // stop the alarm receiver
    public void stop() {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service stoped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```